# Parallel execution for h2o AutoML?

Tags: h2o

Is it possible to kick off h2o's AutoML to train and evaluate models in parallel either locally or on a cluster, using something like joblib or dask?

Comment: You may have trouble finding someone that both known H2O and Dask well enough to answer this. Perhaps you should try something and report back specific problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing out this question as the question has migrated, and more appropriately, belongs elsewhere (i.e. the Google Group).
[Here's](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/DEqGVfOUeh4) where the topic can be found.
Also a reference to H2O posting guidelines [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/h2ostream).

I'll recap the highlights here:

- There's nothing outright that is known right now to do this, BUT:
- H2O builds one model at a time, but the creation of that model is a parallel operation
- You can potentially parallelize by having multiple API clients pointing to the same cluster, operating on different entries of  in the search space

Comment: This isn't an answer, I recommend you delete your question instead.

Comment: Understood. But I'm going to keep it here for archival since these questions may more appropriately belong elsewhere based on h2o's guidelines. Providing a reference there under this context will keep others that go down a similar path from hitting the same issue.

Comment: OK, I won't push you (but others might!)